# Possible to batch view/restore/delete quarantined files from Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

**tl;dr:** Is there a way to batch-view + restore items that have been quarantined by Windows (10) Defender?

In Windows 10, to restore a quarantined file from Windows Defender -- which silently whisks files away into quarantine, willy-nilly, with no indication or heads-up about it -- requires an *absurd* number of clicks:

1. Click Start button
2. Type Virus (Protection) and click/enter
3. Click "Threat history"
4. Click (the wholly unnecessary) drop-down arrow on an individual threat *(...look at all the open unused space to the right -- display the "extra" info and shift the buttons over there, no drop-down necessary!)*
5. Click "See details"
6. Click "Yes" to UAC prompt
7. Now finally able see the **filename** this threat pertains to *(...why isn't the **filename** the default piece of information shown?! And that's assuming only one piece of info can be shown upfront per entry, which is nonsensical)*
8. Click "OK" on the popup modal
9. Click "Restore" button
10. Click "Yes" to UAC prompt (again)

...one quarantined file down. *High-fii-ive!*

I was hoping that NirSoft, i.e. the hero that Gotham needs, may have come to the rescue with a utility that could connect into the Windows Defender backend to display all threat + quarantine information for everything all at once, in tabular format, and, if possible, the spectacular ability to batch-select items and restore (or delete) them all at once, vs. the savage click-fest necessitated via Windows 10's "Control-Settings-Control-Panel" ...and for every individual item. But unfortunately, to no avail (bless his freedom-fighting heart nonetheless, however).

It goes without saying, but this is just one drop in an oceanic-sized bucket of my Windows 10 design gripes. Help us Obi-Win7-Kenobi. You're our only hope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly easy to do with  from the CMD prompt or with a batch script. To list the files in quarantine by script:

- Right-click the desktop and create *New>Notepad document* (or text file).
- Right-click the file and *Edit*.
- Enter the following:

> cd %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender
>
> MpCmdRun.exe -Restore -ListAll
>
> pause

- Save the changes and run the batch file as Administrator.

---

To list the files in quarantine from CMD as Administrator:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd`, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to confirm it in the UAC dialog.
- Enter

  > "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -Restore -ListAll

---

To restore specific files:

- Looking at the list of quarantined items, select by name what should be restored by entering the following:

  > "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -Restore -Name "*filename*"
- Or, to restore *all* files,

  > "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -Restore -All

---

For more information on MpCmdRun, enter `MpCmdRun.exe /?` in a CMD prompt, or see the [description from MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/command-line-arguments-windows-defender-antivirus).

Comment: Bless you, works a treat! Never knew this existed.