# Windows Defender won't delete or restore quarantined threat

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender, quarantine

Windows Defender has quarantined two threats on my PC recently: one is an infected executable on a network share (which was put there deliberately and which someone needs), the other is a simple "potentially unwanted app" from a bundle installer I downloaded for FileZilla.

In Defender's Protection History, when I click on "Restore" or "Remove" for one threat, I get a UAC prompt, then nothing happens when I confirm. After accepting once, I don't get other UAC prompts, but further commands don't do anything either.

The Windows Security task bar icon keeps warning me of the bundle installer, even though I can't remove it.

Why can't I act on quarantined threats, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Let's fix the issue from Command prompt.

First open Command Prompt as Administrator. Then run `cd "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender"`. Now run `MpCmdRun.exe -restore -listall` and you will get a list of quarantined files. Now choose the file you want to restore and run `MpCmdRun.exe -restore -name "Filename"` where `"Filename"` is the file's name you want to restore.

If it does not work, temporarily disable File checking by Windows Security > App & browser control > Check apps and files option set to Off and restore it now. Now again you can turn it on.

Hope that helps

Comment: You sir, Just saved my bacon. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note: There are options to restore all to a specific path. See MpCmdRun.exe -h

Comment: I had to enter the tread name instead of the file name. Also in the help page it states that the -name parameter refers to the thread name. In my case `MpCmdRun.exe -restore -name Trojan:Script/Wacatac.B!ml` worked while the file name didn't. There is also a -filepath parameter.

Comment: @SebastianAx Thanks, that `-Path` option allowed me to restore a file that could not be restored to a network folder

Comment: If I would like to restore a specific file, not a threat type, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> In Defender's Protection History, when I click on "Restore" or "Remove" for one threat, I get a UAC prompt, then nothing happens when I confirm. After accepting once, I don't get other UAC prompts, but further commands don't do anything either.

I had the same issue: it was due to the fact that the file that Windows Defender quarantined was originally in a folder that I had later renamed. This caused restore to fail silently, since Defender didn't know where to restore the file (what a great program). There is no way to specific another folder where to restore the file in the UI: one has to use the CLI.

To fix the issue, open `cmd.exe` as admin and run:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -Restore -name "filename" -Path C:\temp\restoredfiles
```

where:

- `filename`: filename of the file to be restored.
- `C:\temp\restoredfiles`: folder where the file should be restored.

And if all the quarantined files were false positive, one can restore all files at once as follows:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -Restore -All -Path C:\temp\restoredfiles
```

The commands come from [DrMoishe Pippik](https://superuser.com/users/401553/drmoishe-pippik)'s great [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1448590/116475).

As a side note, if one tries to restore the deleted file via CLI without specifying the path (e.g., with `"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -Restore -name "filename"`) and if the original folder was later renamed, one gets the error message:

```
Error code: 0x80508014 Cannot restore a file
```

---

To open `cmd.exe` as admin:

[image]