# Windows Security - Restoring a quarantined file which is not found but exists in the quarantine folder

Tags: windows-10, restore, quarantine

Windows Security has quarantined a text file containing important information. That happened less that 30 days ago, but I cannot see any files in the Windows Security Protection History ("no recent actions"). It seems that the file I need is in the folder
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Quarantine\ResourceData\CD
and is named
CDE7887F857F55D6C99909E0D63CF26C687DCE80

I tried the procedure of restoring a file as described on docs.microsoft.com
“%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe” –Restore –Name EUS:Win32/CustomEnterpriseBlock –All

The result was "no quarantined files".

But I still see the file in the folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Quarantine\ResourceData\CD

Is there any way to restore it?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to manually copy the file from that folder?

Comment: Why on earth would Windows quarantine a non-executable file??

Comment: @Tetsujin: This happens - a virus may include non-executable files.

Comment: it could be a bat file renamed to a text file.

Comment: See this>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-atp/respond-file-alerts#restore-file-from-quarantine

Comment: @Moab thanks, I already tried to restore the file as described on docs.microsoft.com. It gave the result "no quarantined files".

Comment: @Moab No, it was not a bat file, just a txt from my desktop containing logins...

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I copied and renamed it as a txt file, then opened and got something like Chinese script in it...

Comment: problem solved, thanks a lot! https://superuser.com/questions/1448546/possible-to-batch-view-restore-delete-quarantined-files-from-windows-defender?rq=1